# How to extract response body as String/Object from RestClient in case of exception?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-3

Now I have it like this:

```java
protected static ResponseEntity<?> actualResponse;
protected static RestClientResponseException actualErrorResponse;

try{
    actualResponse = REST_CLIENT.get()
            .uri(uriPath, CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(payloadType);
} catch (final RestClientResponseException e) {
    actualErrorResponse = e;
}
```

Is there any way to extract exception in functional style?

I've tried this:

```java
.onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, ((request, response) -> {
    response.getBody()
```

But it returns InputStream that requires addition transforming to String/Exception object.